# Simple triggered Flow, but still "flow Error Occurred: Too many SOQL queries: 101"

Tags: governorlimits, after-trigger

I have a really simple flow no loop, two update elements.
I get the error:

*Error element Update_Account_Owner (FlowRecordUpdate).
This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: Too many SOQL queries: 101. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.*

[image]

Expand on the element that gives the error

[image]

Now if I get the things right I can not use Update element on more than 100 records meaning probably when used like that the element is querying and updating the records one by one and NOT consolidating using only one update DML.

I was Always thinking that a Flow would batch chenges like that, but now when I think about it if they are batched then that would slow down the preformance of the flow and when this is triggered based flow that would not be good for sure.

The true **question** is would this be solved if I apply the apex consolidation best practices:

1. Use get element to get all records
2. Loop the Accounts to make the desired update with assign element
3. Use update element giving the whole list of updated Account to be updated

**OR** to go with a Triger where Iwould have full control?

Comment: I suspect this is simply a recursion issue, with the update in the flow effectively causing the flow to be called again. Add a condition on the flow to verify that the OwnerID isn't already what you will set it to and try again.

Comment: Got your point will try this.

Comment: Is there any other business logic on this object in triggers or flows?